# Where does Sublime Text store its un-saved windows?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I'm using Sublime Text as a notepad and usually I've plenty of un-saved files which usually are re-open after reboot or crash, but I'm afraid to lose them (which happened few times).

Where (in which folder/file) does Sublime Text store these temporary files, so I can do some periodic session backups?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### Where does Sublime Text store its un-saved windows?

This depends on which operating system your are using.

---

#### OSX

Sublime Text 3:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Local/Session.sublime_session
```

Sublime Text 2:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Settings/Auto Save.sublime_session
```

> I'm wondering if there is a location Sublime puts temporary files? I just lost a WP theme I was working on due to MacOSX blundering, wondering if I can get any of the files I was working on back from Sublime temp files.

...

> Sublime Text will save auto save information to ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Settings/Auto Save.sublime_session, but it does so on a regular basis, and the chances are it's overwritten by now, unfortunately.

Source [Temporary Files location?](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2544)

---

#### Windows

For the settings folder you could look for a unique file using:

```
F:\>dir license.sublime_license /s /b
```

For XP that would return:

```
F:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Sublime Text 2\Settings\License.sublime_license
```

Alternatively:

- Open sublime and go to `preferences` > `browse packages`.
- Then to the parent directory and you'll see the settings subdirectory.

**XP**

```
C:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Sublime Text 2\Settings\Auto Save Session.sublime_session
```

**Windows 7**

Sublime Text 2:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Settings
```

Sublime Text 3:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local
```

(section added by [barlop](https://superuser.com/users/42672/barlop))

Answer (score 19):

Windows 7 64bit, Sublime Text 3 saves its working session (including the contents of tabs that were unsaved when the application was closed) to:

`C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Local\Session.sublime_session`

Comment: This is also the case with Windows 10 64Bit

Comment: Also works on Windows 11

Answer (score 15):

In Linux, Sublime text 3 unsaved content is stored in `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session`

Answer (score 8):

#### For **Linux**

In the *Mint* distro, the complete file names/paths opened for each tab of *Sublime Text 3*, can be accessed with this Bash line:

```
cat $HOME/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Auto\ Save\ Session.sublime_session |grep "\"file\":" |sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//g' |sed 's/^\"file\"\: \"//g' |sort -u | sed 's/[\",]*//ig'
```

**NOTE**: If you use `Session.sublime_session` instead of "`Auto Save Session.sublime_session`", you can get different results, with missing tabs/files.

Anyway, this is not 100% reliable, but will get you started. I'm sure you can improve this ugly line, so feel free to comment.

Explanation:

- 1st `sed` removes leading white space due to JSON keys
- 2nd `sed` remove the `"file": "` part
- `sort -u` (unique) remove filename duplicates
- 3rd `sed` remove trailing white space.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, if you are using **portable** sublime text **2**, and did not install it from the repos, you can find it in:

```
~/.config/sublime-text-2/Settings/Session.sublime_session
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had the portable version installed, then the directory is

`<wherever you unzipped it>\Sublime Text Build 3059 x64\Data\Local`

Change your build number accordingly.